# Unable to set RLS in Power BI based on another table

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, row-level-security

I have the following two tables relevant to RLS:

```
DIM_EMPLOYEE (EMAIL, BRANCH_ID)
```

and

```
DIM_BRANCH (BRANCH_ID)
```

There is a `one-to-many` relationship from `DIM_BRANCH` to `DIM_EMPLOYEE` (i.e. filters cascade from `DIM_BRANCH` to `DIM_EMPLOYEE`).
There are also other tables which are filtered by `DIM_BRANCH` however those are not relevant here.

I am trying to configure RLS so that the `DIM_BRANCH` table is filtered using current user's email. This should further propagate the filters to all related tables down the stream.

This is the code that I am trying to use in RLS DAX:

```
DIM_BRANCH[BRANCH_ID] IN 
CALCULATETABLE(
    DIM_EMPLOYEE,
    FILTER(
        DIM_EMPLOYEE,
        DIM_EMPLOYEE[EMAIL] = USERPRINCIPALNAME()
    ),
    VALUES(DIM_EMPLOYEE[BRANCH_ID])
)
```

However it gives me this error:

> A single value for column 'EMAIL' in table 'DIM_EMPLOYEE' cannot be
> determined. This can happen when a measure formula refers to a column
> that contains many values without specifying an aggregation such as
> min, max, count, or sum to get a single result.

I have also tried to replace `VALUES` with `MAX` without any success. My understanding is that it should work because I am using `IN` clause which shouldn't have a problem even with multiple rows.
What part am I doing wrong here? TIA